# HAProxy with docker, consul and mesos, which one to choose?

Tags: docker, load-balancing, mesosphere, consul, dcos

In a microservice stack that uses docker for container orchestration, consul for service discovery and mesos for container scheduling, there are two services that user facing (with GUI) requiring to be configured with HAProxy for load balancing.

The question is, at which level should they be load-balanced. There are some implementations of LB that support each use case. dockercloud-haproxy, fabio with consul and marathon-lb if DC/OS is in place.

What would be a selection criteria ?

Answer (score 0):

If your need is not that pressing you might want to wait until docker 1.12 is stabilised and use the included LB feature, which is pretty slick:
https://blog.docker.com/2016/06/docker-1-12-built-in-orchestration/